# Database Text Cannot be Parsed to JSON

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, json, angularjs

I am receiving text from MySQL through an AJAX call using PHP. When I try `JSON.parse(string)`
I get an error. I validated my JSON and it turns out that MYSQL is giving me some UTF-8 values which JSON can't handle, how would I fix this so I can parse it at the client side?

Example JSON: `While we\u2019re still waiting...`

Sample Javascript:

```
module.controller('OrdersController', function($scope, $http){

$http.get(base_url() + 'orders/?position=' + position)      
    .success(function(data){
    console.log(jQuery.parseJSON(data));
});
```

Comment: have you tried wrapping the json with `utf8_encode` before outputting the ajax response ?

Comment: @shatheesh Yes sir I did and still nothing.

Comment: provide more code and json outputs so that we can help you more

Comment: @shatheesh The rest of the JSON output is valid according to the validator what is causing the problem is the part I showed you, everything else is just too lengthy and irrelevant. I added some Javascript using AngularJS on my edit.

Comment: Get your data as it is from `.success(function(data){ console.log(data) })` it already goes as object if you didn't change `$httpProvider.defaults`

Comment: @UmidbekKarimov Ha! That worked like a charm! I don't get why, however...

Comment: `$http` look at `Content-Type` in headers and parse string to object for you, if it needed

Comment: @UmidbekKarimov Ahhh! That is why it broke when I started using Angular. Create an answer and I will accept it and vote it up, thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$http` look at `Content-Type` in headers and parse string to object for you, if it needed

So you can use your `data` argument as it is:

```
$http.get(base_url() + 'orders/?position=' + position).success(function(data){
    console.log(data);
});
```

Some useful info about [$http](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24http) (look at **Setting HTTP Headers**)